# Excel VBA Lookup two values in same row based on values in three columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: Table]

Basically, "MatGroup" is a subtype of "StorLoc" which is a subtype of "Department".

I need to look for a match in those three columns, then return the values of two of the other columns to the right (those columns represent weeks).

I've highlighted an example in the picture above. There I'm searching for **Department 1101**, **StorLoc 0001** and **MatGroup 1225** in **week 4** and **5**, which should return the values 243 and 245, which can then be added together = 488.

For testing purpose, I have a working formula that does this in the same worksheet:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(XLOOKUP(K6&J8&K7;A2:A40&B2:B40&C2:C40;D2:E40))
```

However, I need a pure VBA solution for this as I'll be pulling this data into a completely separate workbook. I'm not able to use the same solution as in the formula above because apparantly VBA does not allow you to concat multiple criteria with &.

My current solution of using tons of CountIfs is not exactly satisfying and completely a lot more resource intensive than necessary (and messy!):

```
resultCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(dataWorkBook.Range("A" & departmentStartRow & ":BC" & departmentEndRow).Columns(weekNumber + 1), dataWorkBook.Range("B" & departmentStartRow & ":B" & departmentEndRow), StorLoc, dataWorkBook.Range("C" & departmentStartRow & ":C" & departmentEndRow), MatGroup)
```

Comment: VBA accept `&` for concatenation, but two spaces have to exist in front of it and after...

Comment: I tried, but I only get a type mismatch error.
`resultCount0001(storeCategory) = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(storeNo & "0001" & pWS.Range(storeCategoryMatGroup1 & weekNum + 4), oWS.Range("A:A") & oWS.Range("B:B") & oWS.Range("C:C"), oWS.Range("A:B").Offset(weekNum + firstWeek))`
Anyway, I'll check out your other solution below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses an array and should be very fast even for big ranges, working in memory:

```
Sub LookupThreeConditions()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, arr, i As Long
 Dim dep As String, stLoc As String, matGr As String, result As Long
 
 dep = "1101": stLoc = "0001": matGr = "1225"
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set sh1 = sh.Next 'use here the sheet you need to copy in
 
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = sh.Range("A2:F" & lastRow).value 'put the range in an array
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) = dep & stLoc & matGr Then
        result = arr(i, 5) + arr(i, 6): Exit For
    End If
 Next i
 MsgBox "Result is " & result
 sh1.Range("A1").value = result 'use here what range you need
 End Sub
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I'm confusing about`arr = sh.Range("A2:E" & lastRow).value` What if the columns aren't all next to each other? What if I want to get week 4 and 5 instead? I've updated the OP to reflect that.

Comment: I tried your code now and although it made my code neat and tidy in comparison with all the CountIfs I had, it made it run a lot slower. Looping through 6000 rows doesn't seem to be super efficient. :P Keep in mind that I'm also running this code a lot of times subsequently. I'm running this in a loop, checking 12 different matGroups in 2 different StorLocs in 65 different departments. That's 1560 loops, and if I run through 52 weeks (1 year), that's 81.120 loops.

Comment: Nevermind, I made some new optimisations, such as skipping unncessary loops and setting a new array for every Department, limiting the number of rows that have to be looped through. It's quite fast now. :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @Vikestart Did you test the code like it is? Did you try any modification? If  not, it should be very fast, even for 100000 rows. It can easily be modified to become a function, returning the desired result... What does "unnecessary loops" means? The code exits the loop after finding an occurrence.