# Use .Find to Find Two Strings that are placed in the same Row but different Columns

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to use the .Find function to find two strings and determine which row they are in. For this example the two strings that I am looking for are "Wavelenght" and "Test-Config" as shown in the `rowindex = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength", "Test-Config")` line. I have attached all my code. The current script produces an error at `Set parameter_row = Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B").Find(What:=parametername, What:=routingname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)` saying "Named Argument Not Found." I also have already checked and I do not have Solver.xlam in my Available References

```
 Public Sub Main()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, i As Range, dict As Object, sysnum As Integer, sysrow As Integer, syscol As Integer, wsName As String 
Dim wbSrc As Workbook

Dim value As Long, colindex As Long, rowindex As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("Q:\Specification and Configuration Document.xlsx")
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each i In ws.Range("E2:E15").Cells ' i = every WD number
      sysnum = i.value
      sysrow = i.Row
      syscol = i.Column

      If sysnum = "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
      End If
If Not dict.Exists(sysnum) Then ' check if unique value already exists before adding it to dictionary
    dict.Add sysnum, True
    If Not SheetExists(sysnum, ThisWorkbook) Then
        wsName = i.EntireRow.Columns("D").value ' sheet to be copied
        If SheetExists(wsName, wbSrc) Then ' if there is a sheet for wsName to copy
            wbSrc.Worksheets(wsName).Copy After:=ws ' copy the sheet
            wb.Worksheets(wsName).name = sysnum ' rename the copy
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet " & sysnum & " already exists"
    End If
End If

Sheets(1).Select
' Wavelength Turning Range Section
' in sheet 1
colindex = getcolumnindex(ws, "Tuning Range (nm)")
value = getjiradata(sysrow, colindex)

' in SD sheet
rowindex = getrowindex(sysnum, "Wavelength Tuning Range", "Test-Config-OCT")

Next i
End Sub
```

---

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, wb As Workbook)
  On Error Resume Next
  SheetExists = Not wb.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

---

```
Function getcolumnindex(sht As Worksheet, colname As String) As Long 
Dim paramname As Object
Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set paramname = sht.Range("A1:Z2").Find(What:=colname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not paramname Is Nothing Then
        getcolumnindex = paramname.Column
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Function getjiradata(WDrow As Integer, parametercol As Long) 
   Dim cell As Variant, ws As Worksheet
   cell = getcolumnindex(ws, "Tuning Range (nm)")
   getjiradata = Cells(WDrow, parametercol)

End Function
```

---

```
Function getrowindex(WDnum As Variant, parametername As String, routingname As String) As Long 
   Dim parameter_row As Object
   Set parameter_row = Worksheets(sysnum).Range("B:B").Find(What:=parametername, What:=routingname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
      If Not parameter_row Is Nothing Then
          getrowindex = parameter_row.Row
      End If
End Function
```

UPDATE:

```
Function getrowindex(WDnum As Variant, parametername As String, routingname As String) As Long ' finds the row index of parameters in SD tab
Dim parameter_row As Range, ws As Worksheet, rowname As Range, addr As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WDnum)

Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not rowname Is Nothing Then addr = rowname.Address ' remember the first cell found with parametername
    Do While Not rowname Is Nothing
        If rowname.Offset(0, 1).Value = routingname Then ' check column C for cell with routingname
            getrowindex = rowname.Row
            Exit Function
        End If
    Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").FindNext(after:=rowname)
        If rowname.Address = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
 End Function
```

Comment: You cannot use `What` as a parameter twice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67952490/excel-vba-lookup-two-values-in-same-row-based-on-values-in-three-columns. Likely the answer here will be to use an array.

Comment: @BigBen In the question you linked, they hard coded what `dep, stLoc, and matGr` are, is there a way to not do that? For my code function `rowindex` should be able to be called with different strings

Comment: Sure, that linked thread is just an example (and there may be a better example out there). But basically, keep the parameters you already have (`parametername`, `routingname`), then read the data you're looking at into an array, then loop the array.

Comment: @BigBen so i could say `Dim Array(1 to 2) as String, Array as Integer  Array(1) = parametername Array(2) = routingname` and then use `.Find(What:=Array`?

Comment: "Find Two Strings that are placed in the same Row but different Columns" - you can't do that by looking only in ColB...

Comment: @TimWilliams I have changed the range to be Col B and C since those are the two locations of the `What:=` but I am still getting an error of "Named argument not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to find *Wavelength Tuning Range*.  Once found you just need to check if the second column contains *Test-Config-OCT*.

I've given two functions - the first will return all instances of the found rows, the second will stop when it finds the first row.

You need to pass the function the first column range reference, the number of columns across that the second item will appear in, the value to look for in the first column and the value to look for in the second column:
`ReturnRowReference(RangeToSearch, OffSetColumn, FirstItem, SecondItem)`

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim MyResult As Range
    Set MyResult = ReturnRowReference(Sheet1.Range("C7:D14"), 2, "Wavelength Tuning Range", "Test-Config-OCT")
    
    Dim MyFirstResult As Range
    Set MyFirstResult = ReturnFirstRowReference(Sheet1.Range("C7:D14"), 2, "Wavelength Tuning Range", "Test-Config-OCT")
    
    If Not MyResult Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox MyResult.Address & vbCr & vbCr & _
               MyFirstResult.Address, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub



Public Function ReturnRowReference(RangeToSearch As Range, OffsetColumns As Long, FirstItem As String, SecondItem As String) As Range

    With RangeToSearch
        'Start looking after the last cell in the column.... which equates to the first cell in the column.
        Dim FoundRange As Range
        Set FoundRange = .Find(What:=FirstItem, After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                               MatchCase:=True)
                               
        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            Dim FirstAddress As String
            FirstAddress = FoundRange.Address
            Do
                If FoundRange.Offset(, OffsetColumns) = SecondItem Then
                    Dim ReturnRange As Range
                    If ReturnRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set ReturnRange = FoundRange.EntireRow
                    Else
                        Set ReturnRange = Union(ReturnRange, FoundRange.EntireRow)
                    End If
                End If
                Set FoundRange = .FindNext(FoundRange)
            Loop While FoundRange.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
    
    Set ReturnRowReference = ReturnRange

End Function

Public Function ReturnFirstRowReference(RangeToSearch As Range, OffsetColumns As Long, FirstItem As String, SecondItem As String) As Range

    With RangeToSearch
        'Start looking after the last cell in the column.... which equates to the first cell in the column.
        Dim FoundRange As Range
        Set FoundRange = .Find(What:=FirstItem, After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1), _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                               MatchCase:=True)
                               
        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            If FoundRange.Offset(, OffsetColumns) = SecondItem Then
                Set ReturnFirstRowReference = FoundRange.EntireRow
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

This is the data I used:
[image]

and this is the message box it returned.
So first procedure found rows 7 & 11, second procedure only found row 7.
[image]

Update to OP's edited code:

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox getrowindex("Sheet1", "Wavelength Tuning Range", "Test-Config-OCT")

End Sub

Public Function getrowindex(WDnum As Variant, parametername As String, routingname As String) As Long ' finds the row index of parameters in SD tab

    Dim parameter_row As Range, ws As Worksheet, rowname As Range, addr As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WDnum) 'Changed Sheets to Worksheets.  Sheets also includes Chart Sheets and Old style macro sheets.

    Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").Find(What:=parametername, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
    
    If Not rowname Is Nothing Then 'Check that something is found.
        addr = rowname.Address ' remember the first cell found with parametername.
        Do
            If rowname.Offset(0, 1).Value = routingname Then ' check column C for cell with routingname
                getrowindex = rowname.Row
                Exit Do 'Found the correct row so exit the loop.
            End If
            Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").FindNext(after:=rowname)
        Loop While rowname.Address <> addr 'We know that rowname is not nothing at this point, so just check if it's back at the first address.
    End If
    
 End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, while waiting for an answer I found a code and modified it to my needs. Would you say this this approach is just as efficient as the one you posted? I have posted it above

Comment: It looks like it will work, but you're checking if `rowname` is nothing twice.  Would be better to move the `addr = rowname.Address` to the next line, change the `Do` line to just `Do` and loop while rowname.address <> addr.  I'd also change `Exit Function ` to `Exit Do` so there's a single exit point for the function.

Comment: Where is the change `Do` line to just `Do`?

Comment: Your updated code has `Do While Not rowname Is Nothing` - be better as just `Do`.

Comment: When replacing with `Do` do i  not need `rowname is Nothing`

Comment: Not if you've already checked that rowname is not nothing.  I'll update my answer with an edited version of your last update.

Comment: I just saw it and made the changes! What do you mean by `check if it's back at the first address.` Thank you!

Comment: `FindNext` will wrap back to the top of the find range.  We know that it's found something, so the loop needs to check for when the Find operation loops back to the first found item again.

Comment: But I do not have it say `FindNext` in this function? Unless thats what `Loop While` means

Comment: It does use `FindNext`.... `Set rowname = ws.Columns("B").FindNext(after:=rowname)`   Fourth line from the bottom.